# Ping multiple IP address and write to file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, ip

I need help making a script that can pings multiple IP addresses in a list, and writes the one/ones it successfully pinged into a file.

Comment: And what have you done until now ? Can you post your actual script ?

Comment: Just give a try with this batch file [Multi Ping Tester with colors](https://pastebin.com/zjYwSqUM)

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

@echo off

:pings

ping [Insert the ip here]

echo Pinged [Insert the ip here]>PingedIps.txt

And then goto something like ping2 with this: goto ping2 at the end
If when you ping the ips it overwrites the txt file try >> instead of >.

Comment: dosn't answer the question (mulitple addresses, write to file only if successful).